# tcolorbox empty title but with frame?

Tags: titles, boxes, tcolorbox

I want a box with the header frame for empty title. How can I do that? If I remove the title, the header frame will be removed automatically. I've tried to put an empty title so that I can keep the header frame but with no luck.

```
\begin{frame}[t]
    \frametitle{KKKKKKKK}
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=green!5, colframe=green!30!black, title = {}]

\end{tcolorbox}
\end{frame}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Test}
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=green!5, colframe=green!30!black, title = {\strut}]
Test
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Instead of `\strut` you could use an empty box: `\mbox{}`, or a phantom: `\phantom{Ag}`- Here's the result with an empty box:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Test}
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=green!5, colframe=green!30!black, title = {\mbox{}}]
Test
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: how to reduce the height of the header? It is a little big.

Comment: @CroCo As I said, change `\strut` to `\mbox{}`.

Comment: ^^ sorry I commented before your update. Thanks it worked

Comment: @CroCo Ah, I see. No problem. In any case, I updated the answer with an example using the box.

Answer (score 0):

You can add toprule in the options. [(page 22)](http://sunsite.informatik.rwth-aachen.de/ftp/pub/mirror/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=green!5, colframe=green!30!black,toprule=12pt]

\end{tcolorbox}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Notice that this dosen't exactly give the shape for the upper part as with a real title.

Comment: @SLx64, it gives me error.

Comment: @Gonzalo Medina Oh yes, you're right! CroCo Could you post the error message please?

Comment: `! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tcb/toprule' and I am going to`